# Dark Knight Rises data upload

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

At the beginning of "Dark Knight Rises", Bane and his crew are uploading something at the stock exchange.

Spoiler Background:

> When they are stationary in the building Bane says it will take 8 minutes to complete the upload.  Assuming that they were using a 3G connection which is (at best) 2Mbit/s while stationary, the upload rate would increase by about a factor of 10 as soon as they started moving on the motorcycles.

Spoiler Question:

> How could this upload have completed by the time Batman got the tablet?

Comment: _"a 3G connection which is (at best) 2Mbit/s while stationary"_ Eh, no. Your mobile operator is being stingy in their infrastructure and lying to you about it. "3G" is a term denoting a wide range of standards, some of which can achieve as much as 56Mbps downstream!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not watching 24! Or in other words: Time isn't always constant, especially during some action scenes with some kind of time bomb (or at least some timer) and this doesn't apply to the Matrix trilogy or Max Payne only. I haven't seen the movie yet, but it's just like it works in almost any work of fiction: "We've got 10 minutes till something happens." And 2 minutes later only 60 seconds are left, despite the time that passed being shorter. It might even happen that the last 10 seconds then happen 2 or 3 minutes later, just because they wanted to show something happen in between these seconds.

In case the actual stuff happening is believably shorter than these 8 minutes, then I'd guess it's just some shortcomming story wise or something they forgot to adjust to something more believable.

Comment: Yep. This is every action movie ever. I just need some sort of countdown indicator so know where I'm at.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect time is changing - it's interesting that they get on the bikes during the day and then half way through the chase it's night time.

Comment: Well if I recall properly.  They went under the bridge during the day time, then the lights went out, then when they exited the bridge it was night time.  I think that was just for the movie experience.  Probably no "explanation for it."

Comment: OR....continuity error as it happens in movies. They shot it during the day and night and forgot to account for the night when they noticed it during editing.

Answer (score 2):

If you notice, the robery happened in broad daylight.  By the time Batman got the device it was dark out.  One could assume that more than 8 minutes passed during the chase through the city, but it's not clearly identified so the viewer is left to somewhat fill in the gaps.